# Condition within the while without returning rows from the database

Tags: php

I want you to assign the value to select automatically.

The problem I am having is when the table is empty it does not assign a value to select. Let me explain.

CODE:

```
<select class="form-control1" name="Orcamento" id="Orcamento" required>
  <option></option>
  <?php                   
   $sql = "SELECT Orcamento FROM dados.Encomendas ORDER BY Orcamento DESC LIMIT 1";
   $sql = $conn->prepare($sql); 
   $sql->execute();
   while($ln = $sql->fetch()){
     $row_count = $ln->rowCount(); 
     $orcam = $ln['Orcamento'] + 1;
     if($row_count < 1){
      echo '<option value="' . $orcam. '" style="background-color: transparent !important; color: black !important;">'. $orcam.'</option>';
     }else{
      echo '<option value="1" style="background-color: transparent !important; color: black !important;">1</option>';
     }

   }
  ?>        
</select>
```

If you already have rows inserted in the table, it works correctly. But if the table is still empty, then you must assign a value of 1 to the select, but it is not. The select is empty.

Comment: do you use `PDO` or `mysqli` for the database connection?

Comment: @Marcello Perri PDO I misread the question

Comment: no, I mean which one of those?  `PDO` or `mysqli`?

Comment: Use the do-while loop because it returns at least one option if the table doesn't have a record

Comment: @Bruno I left an answer below

Comment: when the table is empty, the condition will not be true so it will not come down to your child condition where you asked to set 1 in option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to know if you are using `PDO` or `mysqli`, because your database connection is an object I am assuming you are not using `mysql`.

I would try this:

```
<select class="form-control1" name="Orcamento" id="Orcamento" required>
  <option></option>
  <?php                   
   $sql = "SELECT Orcamento FROM dados.Encomendas ORDER BY Orcamento DESC LIMIT 1";
   $sql = $conn->prepare($sql); 
   $sql->execute();

   // if result is empty display only a option
   if ($sql->rowCount() == 0) {
       echo '<option value="1" style="background-color: transparent !important; color: black !important;">1</option>';
   }else{
       // if we have multiple rows display options
       while($ln = $sql->fetch()){

          $orcam = $ln['Orcamento'] + 1;
          echo '<option value="' . $orcam. '" style="background-color: transparent !important; color: black !important;">'. $orcam.'</option>';

       }
   }
  ?>        
</select>
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: I'm using the PDO

Comment: That should be ok for PDO